# How to use res.render() inside of Mongoose's Model.find()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to render Mongoose models inside of a Handlebars each loop. From what I can tell, res.render() should be called inside of the find query but this doesn't work. The page never loads and eventually ends in ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I'm new to Mongoose and Node.js in general, so apologies for any obvious oversights.

Here's the main file where the request is made.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();

var Product = require('../models/product.js');

router.get('/shop', (req, res) => {
  Product.find((err, product) => {
    res.render('shop.hbs', {
      title: 'Shop',
      products: product
    });
  });
});
```

The Mongoose model.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
  description: {type: String, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

Seeder file.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Product = require('../models/product');

var products = [
  new Product({
    description: 'Example 1',
  }),
  new Product({
    description: 'Example 2',
  })
];

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/products', {useNewUrlParser: true});

var done = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].save((err, result) => {
    done++;
    if (done === products.length) {
      exit();
    }
  });
}

var exit = () => {
  mongoose.disconnect();
};
```

Simplified Handlebars file where I want the models rendered.

```
<div id="shop">
  {{# each products}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you're using the right syntax for Product.find(), the first parameter should be your search expression. If you want all products, you'd pass an empty object:

```
  Product.find({}, (err, products) => {
        // Your rendering logic
  });
```